# Using format in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, format, currency-formatting

I have some problems with my DGV, the DGV is bounded by a datatable with atleast 30 columns (all expect PK and FKs, are set as String), now there is a specific column that is the cost of the product which I want to make it like this sample: 359.99 €, every time the user clicks on that columns cell it will show nullvalue 0.00 €, the currency symbol can't be edited inside the cell, so is the dot seperator.

So that is my goal, and I am trying to do everything I mentioned in the windows form, I have tried by code, however it didn't do anything. At the end what kind of steps should I take for the desired result?

I have tried the following code for that column, however as I said before, it does nothing, though I found a similar question to mine in StarkOverflow, it seems it could be that I should enter this code before binding to DGV (actually I didn't bind it by code, I think I don't need that right now), but I think that is not possible because I need the DGV binded so I can edit it (there is also one unbound column, containing delete buttons for rows, but I dont think it matters here):

```
            advancedDataGridView1.Columns[14].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2";
            advancedDataGridView1.Columns[14].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that you store the cost as a string and Format wont work with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure “why” you would want to store a “COST” value as a `string.` Cost implies a numeric `decimal` value and it “should” be stored in the DB as a `decimal` or other numeric value, but NOT as a `string.` This is going to create more work every time the `string` is used in a numeric context… as is your current case.

Additionally, this could leave the DB in an inconsistent state if some user types “Hello” as a “Cost” value. Something smells fishy and this would appear to actually “create” problems.

Is there some reason you are saving a “Cost” value as a `string`?

Setting the cells format to “c2” is not going to do anything “when” the column “type” is a `string.`

When formatting, the cell has to be of the proper “type” to format it properly. In this case, a `decimal` type would work for a currency value.

Also, it should be noted, that if your code “manually” adds the columns to the grid, then the lines of code…

```
dataGridView1.Columns[14].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2";
dataGridView1.Columns[14].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
```

… will obviously not work BEFORE these columns are added.

The same would apply when using a `DataSource.` You FIRST add the `DataSource`, THEN the code formats the column(s).

Again, this all seems very strange to store a `decimal` value into the DB as a `string.` I am making this assumption as your code “could” technically convert the `decimal` value in the DB to a `string` in the query. If this is the case, then a simple fix is to alter the query to not convert the value to a `string.`

Below is an example of what is described above. The example uses a `DataTable` as a `DataSource.` It has two columns such that the first column is a `decimal` type and the second column is of a `string` type. The table has some rows added such that each row has the “same” value in each column.

[image]

When the formatting is applied after the grid’s `DataSource` has been set, it should be clear, that the formatting is being “ignored” on the cells that are of `string` type and ARE applied to cells of the `decimal` type.

Since the culture info is set to “fr-FR”, then the “decimal point” is NOT used. Therefore when the user types in numbers, the user needs to use a “comma” where they want the decimal place to be.

For a complete example, drop a `DataGridView` onto a form and use the posted code below to test what is described above. I hope this makes sense.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  dataGridView1.DataSource = GetTable();
  dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2";
  dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
  dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "c2";
  dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.FormatProvider = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR");
}

private DataTable GetTable() {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Col0", typeof(decimal));
  dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(string));
  dt.Rows.Add(12.345, 12.345);
  dt.Rows.Add(1.35, 1.35);
  dt.Rows.Add(112.555, 112.555);
  dt.Rows.Add(12.333, 12.333);
  return dt;
}

private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e) {
  Debug.WriteLine("Error at Row: " + e.RowIndex + " Col: " + e.ColumnIndex);
  Debug.WriteLine("Error is:" + e.Exception.Message);
  Debug.WriteLine("Value is:" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].EditedFormattedValue);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and yes I understand that it's not logical to use string for cost, however my situation is that I am using advanced datagridview which has a built-in filter, I really like it and it's necessary for my goal, though when I am trying to sort a numeric type the program crashes, while if i use it on a column with string that contains numbers it sorts very well for me. So that's why I chose to do everything string, and think of something later. Maybe there was easier way to do everything without reconstructing everything, but I really have limited knowledge with databases.

Comment: I think I understand what to do now! Thank you!

Comment: I have to ask, if your numeric values are strings, when sorted would not those string be sorted like... 1, 10, 12, 14, 2, 21, 22, 3, 31... etc.... in other words, numbers do not sort properly when they are strings.

Comment: @Linas MitkevičiusIf … you check my code example; the first column will sort properly by clicking on the column header. It will not sort properly for the string column. I have to ask… is your code “manually” adding the rows to grid? Or is the grid using a `DataSource`? Using a `DataSource` is the better approach as adding the rows manually will just create more work for you. Are you using a `DataSource` to the grid?

Comment: @Linas MitkevičiusIf  … When using the out of the box advanced grid, it would not sort or filter for me regardless if the column was a string or a numeric value. Are you doing anything code wise to achieve this filtering and sorting? I do not want to dissuade you from using the advanced grid, however, a regular grid will sort and filter just fine when done properly. I will assume I am missing something. Good Luck.